# Data Cleaning Python: Replacing the values of a column not within a range with NaN and then dropping the raws which contain NaN

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

I am doing kind of research and need to delete the raws containing some values which are not in a specific range using Python.

**My Dataset in Excel:**

[image]

1. I want to replace the big values of column A (not within range 1-20) with NaN. Replace Big values of column B (not within range 21-40) and so on.
2. Now I want to drop/ delete the raws contains the NaN values

**Expected output should be like:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to solve your problem. Here, I tried to simulate your problem and solve it with below given code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv('c.csv')
print(data)
data['A'] = data['A'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x in range(1,10,1) else x)
data['B'] = data['B'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x in range(10,20,1) else x)
data['C'] = data['C'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x in range(20,30,1) else x)
print(data)
data = data.dropna()
print(data)
```

**Orignal data:**

```
    A   B   C
0   1  10  20
1   2  11  22
2   4  15  25
3   8  20  30
4  12  25  35
5  18  40  55
6  20  45  60
```

**Output with NaN:**

```
      A     B     C
0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   NaN  20.0  30.0
4  12.0  25.0  35.0
5  18.0  40.0  55.0
6  20.0  45.0  60.0
```

**Final Output:**

```
      A     B     C
4  12.0  25.0  35.0
5  18.0  40.0  55.0
6  20.0  45.0  60.0
```

**Try this for non-integer numbers:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv('c.csv')
print(data)
data['A'] = data['A'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x in (round(y,2) for y in np.arange(1.00,10.00,0.01)) else x)
data['B'] = data['B'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x in (round(y,2) for y in np.arange(10.00,20.00,0.01)) else x)
data['C'] = data['C'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x in (round(y,2) for y in np.arange(20.00,30.00,0.01)) else x)
print(data)
data = data.dropna()
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
       A      B      C
0   1.25  10.56  20.11
1   2.39  11.19  22.92
2   4.00  15.65  25.27
3   8.89  20.31  30.15
4  12.15  25.91  35.64
5  18.29  40.15  55.98
6  20.46  45.00  60.48
       A      B      C
0    NaN    NaN    NaN
1    NaN    NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN    NaN
3    NaN  20.31  30.15
4  12.15  25.91  35.64
5  18.29  40.15  55.98
6  20.46  45.00  60.48
       A      B      C
4  12.15  25.91  35.64
5  18.29  40.15  55.98
6  20.46  45.00  60.48
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working..
data['A'] = data['A'].apply(lambda x: x if x in range(1,20,1) else np.nan)
data['B'] = data['B'].apply(lambda x: x if x in range(20,40,1) else np.nan)
data['C'] = data['C'].apply(lambda x: x if x in range(40,60,1) else np.nan)
data['D'] = data['D'].apply(lambda x: x if x in range(60,80,1) else np.nan)
print(data)

Comment: Hi @Himmat. Thanks for your kind help. But it is only working for integer data, not for floating point data, could you kindly help?

Comment: Solution added to work with non-integer values. Please check it and let know if any other help required.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
df= df.drop(df.index[df.idxmax()])
```

O/P:

```
    A   B   C   D
0    1  21  41  61
1    2  22  42  62
2    3  23  43  63
3    4  24  44  64
4    5  25  45  65
5    6  26  46  66
6    7  27  47  67
7    8  28  48  68
8    9  29  49  69
13  14  34  54  74
14  15  35  55  75
15  16  36  56  76
16  17  37  57  77
17  18  38  58  78
18  19  39  59  79
19  20  40  60  80
```

use `idxmax` and drop the returned index.